# Suppose $\{f > λ\}$ is measurable for each rational number $λ$. Is $f$ measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm trying to solve this. I get that it should be related to Borel sigma algebra, but have difficulties with proving this regularly:

> Suppose $\{f > λ\}$ is measurable for each rational number $λ$. Is $f$
>   measurable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint.** Yes, this is true. The following two lemma's give the desired result. Try to prove the following two standard results from measure theory from scratch.

*Lemma 1.* The Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbf{R}$ can be generated by all intervals of the form $(\lambda,\infty)$ for all $\lambda\in \mathbf{Q}$.

*Lemma 2.* Let $(A,\mathscr{A})$ and $(B,\mathscr{B})$ be measure spaces, where $\mathscr{B}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by some set $S$. Then  $f:A\to B$ is mesurable if and only if $f^{-1}(S)\subset \mathscr{A}$.

Comment: How should I understand  {f>λ}? Is this right {f>λ}={x\inR s.t. f(x)>λ} ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, or in other words $f^{-1}\big((\lambda,\infty)\big)$.